# PHP script to fetch data from mysql to android

Tags: php, android, mysql

i have this script and i want to edit it so that it sends extra information  to my android application  from user table after checking if user already exists   `userStatues` and `userPosition`

**PS** : i tried to edit it myself but i don't have proper knowledge in php to make it work or have time to learn php for the moment.. so kindly help if u can :)

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="";
$database_localhost ="";
$username_localhost ="";
$password_localhost ="";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query_search = "select * from user where username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password. "'";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);
//echo $rows;
 if($rows == 0) { 
 echo "No Such User Found"; 
 }
 else  {
    echo "User Found"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: So you want to echo the userStatuses and userPosition fields, right?

Comment: Also, in what manner do you expect the android application to get the data, is it just from the webpage's text after loading. Finally, are the db fields also called userStatuses and userPosition?

Comment: yes and i want to fetch those fields to my android application after the user successfully login

Comment: So something like this: In the first line of the page output, you have userStatuses, in the second one, userPosition. Right?

Comment: u can show me how to return one field and i will do the rest 
i already have PHP script that fetches the data from db to android but i want to edit the above script so that it do both " login process " and " fetching relevant data "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after fixing @Lightwind answer's , here's the answer

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="";
$database_localhost ="";
$username_localhost ="";
$password_localhost ="";
$options_localhost  = array (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>  PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$localhost = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname_localhost;dbname=$database_localhost;charset=utf8", $username_localhost, $password_localhost,$options_localhost);

$username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING , NULL) ;;
$password = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING , NULL) ;

$query  =  "select * from user where username = :username AND password = :password";
$sql     =$localhost->prepare ($query);
$sql->bindparam(':username', $username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindparam(':password', $password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();

$results = $sql->fetchObject();

if (count($results) == 0) {
    echo "No Such User Found";
} else {
    echo "User Found";
    $data = array("status" => $results->userStatus);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution you have right now is very vulnerable to SQL Injection. Here's a nice link telling you what that is: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

To fix this, you should use something like PDO. Since you stated you don't have time to research these things, even though I would strongly recommend doing so to avoid any vulnerabilities like this one, I will replace your entire code with the non-vulnerable version:

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="";
$database_localhost ="";
$username_localhost ="";
$password_localhost ="";
$localhost = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname_localhost;dbname=database_localhost", $username_localhost, $password_localhost);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = "select * from user where username = :username AND password = :password";
$query->bindValue(':username', $username);
$query->bindValue(':password', $password);
$query->execute;

$results = $query->fetchAll();

if(count($results) == 0)
    echo "No Such User Found";
else {
    echo "User Found";
    $data = array("userStatuses" => $results[0]["userStatuses"]
              "userPosition" => $results[0]["userPosition"]);

    echo json_encode($data)

    // OR

    echo $results[0]["userStatuses"].'<br/>'.$results[0]["userPosition"];
}
?>
```

Comment: i fixed ur answer a little and it now works just fine i will post the the fixed answer , thanks dude :)

Comment: @MohNage7 Thanks for fixing it bro :D

Answer (score 0):

After this portion of your code

```
$query_search = "select * from user where username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password. "'";

$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);
//echo $rows;
if($rows == 0) { 
   echo "No Such User Found"; 
 }
 else  {
    echo "User Found"; 
 }
```

Do the following

```
$otherDetails = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_exec) ) {
    $otherDetails['userStatues'];
    $otherDetails['userPosition'];
}
//$otherDetails contains what you want
//you can send it down as json
echo json_encode( $otherDetails );
```

PLEASE NOTE:
The line below present in your code:

```
$query_search = "select * from user where username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password. "'";
```

Is source of security issues. E.g SQL injection and also shows that you are not encrypting your passwords in the database.

Use Php PDO to solve the SQL injection problem and use some hashing algorithms to solve the plain text password problem.

Cheers

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection, why not use PDO?

Comment: Oh there's more! The fact that he is selecting the user with a password without any hashing what so ever suggests that the password is saved in plain text! Which is a security risk also. I just used the code he was already working with so i don't cause more confusion.

Comment: Yeah, @MohNage7 I would recommend reading more into these things, you will cause a lot of security issues otherwise

Comment: @Makville   it returns an empty array , but hey thanks ;)